# How to create a sprite from a video converted to base64 in PIXI.js?

Tags: javascript, base64, pixi.js

I'm new in **PIXI.js** and I have a pretty specific task. I have to distribute my app as `index.html + main.js` files so anybody can open it without internet connection and just by double-clicking on `index.html`, in other words, I have to make my app running without a web server.
I found the solution with converting my assets to base64 in advance and it works for images and sounds but not for videos.
Is there a way to make PIXI create a video sprite from base64 string `data:video/mp4;base64,...`? Or any other way to reach my goal - working without web-server.

Comment: you can have only those 2 files? No other *.mp4 etc files allowed?

Comment: @domis86 the problem is I can't have a web-server and PIXI.js doesn't allow loading files from file system, like `file://` - it complains about cross origin requests. That's why I'm looking for another way to do it.

Comment: Please read - https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/33 - as you see it is problematic to make browser to allow loading of "local file". It is not pixi.js fault.

Comment: But about using base64 video data - can you try advices from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766604/3174731 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the video was soundless so I ended up with [AnimatedSprite](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.AnimatedSprite.html) built on video frames encoded in base64.